# Python CSS Parser

Tags: python, html, css

I am experimenting with CSS files in Python to assist colour blind people. I need to get inside every selector block and change the 'background:' and 'color:'. I tried using CSS parsers like `tinycss` but they are not concentrating on getting selectors.

Example input:

```css
body {background:#fff; color:#ccc}
```

And output:

```css
body {background:#000; color:#aaa}
```

Comment: can you show what is the `input` and waht you want the `output` like

Comment: INPUT: 
"body{background:#fff; color:#ccc}"...and many blocks like this.
OUTPUT:
"body{background:#000; color:#aaa}" [color changed according to specifications given]

Comment: As a tip, please be aware that some people can't see any colours at all. Simply changing the colours isn't enough. In order to be able to do this properly, you need to add additional cues so that colour alone isn't the only way to distinguish information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by using regular expressions. So I kind of ended up making my own parser. I formed a regular expression to search for color patterns such as #XXX, #XXXXXX, rgb(X,X,X), hsl(X,X,X) in the CSS file, maintained a list to keep the positions they are in the CSS file. Then I just re-wrote all the colors at the positions specified by list. This is the best summary I can give for what I did. Please add comment if you need a very detailed explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

http://cthedot.de/cssutils/

```
parser = CSSParser()
# optionally
parser.setFetcher(fetcher)
sheet = parser.parseFile('test1.css', 'ascii')
print sheet.cssText
```

it's pretty simple to use in css processing.

to work with selectors you could use `cssutils.css.SelectorList` and `cssutils.css.Selector`

Comment: it's library has a pretty documentation.

Comment: I am trying hard to do it but selector class is related to CSSStylerule class. I am having a hard time to figure out its significance here. Its really bugging me now :(